# Arduino Uno is making errors when doing calculations

Tags: c++, arduino-uno

So I have been working with my Arduino to make a calculator, and thats what I did. Although, it did not work as I expected it to. When I input simple calculations, it spits it out fine, but when I put in complicated calculations, it goes berserk! It tells me that 9999 * 9 is about -14554 or something like that. Here is the code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <LCD.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE);
const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 4;
char keys [ROWS] [COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3', '+'},
  {'4', '5', '6', '-'},
  {'7', '8', '9', '*'},
  {'C', '0', '=', '/'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {13,12,11,10};
byte colPins[COLS] = {9,8,7,6};
Keypad myKeypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
boolean ansPresent = false;
boolean opSelected = false;
boolean final = false;
String num1, num2;
int answer;
char op;
void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Arduino");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Calculator");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
}
void loop(){
  char key = myKeypad.getKey();
  if (ansPresent == false && key != NO_KEY && (key=='1'||key=='2'||key=='3'||key=='4'||key=='5'||key=='6'||key=='7'||key=='8'||key=='9'||key=='0')) {
    if (opSelected == false) {
      num1 = num1 + key;
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);;
      lcd.print(num1);
    }
    else {
      num2 = num2 + key;
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(num2);
      final = true;
    }
  }
  else if (ansPresent == false && opSelected == false && key != NO_KEY && (key == '/' || key == '*' || key == '-' || key == '+')) {
    opSelected = true;
    op = key;
    lcd.setCursor(15, 0);
    lcd.print(op);
    lcd.setCursor(15, 1);
    lcd.print("=");
  }
  else if (ansPresent == false && final == true && key != NO_KEY && key == '=') {
    if (op == '+'){
      answer = num1.toInt() + num2.toInt();
    }
    else if (op == '-') {
      answer = num1.toInt() - num2.toInt();
    }
    else if (op == '*') {
      answer = num1.toInt() * num2.toInt();
    }
    else if (op == '/') {
      answer = num1.toInt() / num2.toInt();
    }     
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print(answer);
      ansPresent = true;
  }
  else if (key != NO_KEY && key == 'C') {
    lcd.clear();
    ansPresent = false;
    opSelected = false;
    final = false;
    num1 = "";
    num2 = "";
    answer = 0;
    op = ' ';
  }
}
```

Is there a reason why it's doing this?

Comment: That is strange.  Shouldn't be `-14554`.  I'd have expected it to be `-24455`.

Comment: Time to step through in a debugger?

Comment: `#include <cinttypes>`, and then use `std::int64_t` for your operands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does look like an overflow on a 16-bit signed integer which is [what the Arduino Uno uses internally](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/int/). Numbers > 32767 cannot be represented with this. It's not an error, it's a limitation of that hardware, it's just 16-bit.

You need to use multiple `int` values in order to hold anything larger.

Comment: I understand, but how would I break up the string of numbers before turning it into an integer?

Comment: You could try doing the math as decimal characters instead if you want a challenge, or find a "bigint" library for the Uno.

Comment: That's cool, but would it matter if the decimals were over a certain number of digits?

Comment: Try [stuff like this](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=85692.0). Search for "bigint" or "arbitrary precision".

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.

Comment: It looks super complicated, I have no idea of how to implement that into my code

Comment: I am fairly new to C++

Comment: I have a question, is it just the calculation that cant handle numbers 32767 to -32767 or is it the output. If it is the calculation, then I will just make an if statement to check if one or both of the numbers is above or below that limit.

Comment: The chip itself is incapable of dealing with numbers outside of that range *with that type*. If you look in the documentation you can find [other types like `long`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/long/) which have different ranges. For a "calculator" you probably want > 2 billion, so this is where arbitrary precision comes in. That's what pocket calculators have been using since the days of the 4-bit [Intel 4004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_4004) which nonetheless was able to operate on much bigger numbers than 7.

Comment: Do I need to use the arbitrary precision or can I just use long variables to have calculations in the billions? Also, how can I convert a string into just a variable because I use the string to add numbers without having them combined, just as digits.

Comment: Look at the limits of `long` and then the limits of what you need done. If you want to go outside those bounds, you're not going to be able to use `long`, so it's arbitrary precision time.

Comment: If you want to try and write a "string math" library you're welcome to, but these libraries do it more efficiently with binary representation.

Comment: The LCD screen can only display 16 characters so I'm probably only going to need the long vars. If I do it this way, I will have to convert "key" var to a string and then add it to the long one, is that how it works?

Comment: If you want floating point, if you want > ~9 digits you're going to need arbitrary precision. Not sure why you're fussing over this, because it's just how it's done. The 4004 powered many, many calculators capable of doing calculations in the quadrillions and it's barely a CPU by modern definitions.

Comment: Ok ill do the arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino Uno uses an ATmega. On that board an int is a 16bit signed value with range -32,768 to 32,767.

This means your multiplication overflows and what you see printed out is - according to the documentation - "unpredictable". So make sure you dont do that.

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/int/

> Notes and Warnings When signed variables are made to exceed their
> maximum or minimum capacity they overflow. The result of an overflow
> is unpredictable so this should be avoided. A typical symptom of an
> overflow is the variable "rolling over" from its maximum capacity to
> its minimum or vice versa, but this is not always the case. If you
> want this behavior, use unsigned int.